# Insert an integer into a string for a small emb

Tags: string, embedded, system

I'm writing a serial routine for a small embedded system. This is my code which sends out data to a RS232 chip:

strcpy(Buffer,"@2 RMOV -16000 \r\n");
TX_Buffer(Buffer);

The number -16000 is a variable. If there anyway I can insert it into this string? I haven't written code for the printf function.

Comment: What environment / compiler are you using? What part of the C library does it include?

Comment: I'm using Microchip's XC8 compiler. I need to look up what's in the C library for strings.

Comment: If the C library include `sprintf`, then you can do `sprintf(Buffer, "@2 RMOV %d \r\n", value); TX_Buffer(Buffer);`.

Comment: Check if the library contains `itoa`. You can call `TX_Buffer` several times with the same result as a single call. So you can send first the constant prefix string, then the converted number, and finally the constant suffix string.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I should've check the Library first. They have everything I need. I'm going into work to try out the printf() and sprintf().